# Accessing component's "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update the Counter component to take onIncrement and onDecrement
callbacks as props and ensure they update the counter’s values
independently.

Each callback **can only take a single integer** as parameter
which tells the amount to increment the counter’s existing value.

I believe the best way to do this is to access the 'key' prop of the Counter component?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-sound-5ofef?from-embed
App.js

```
import Counter from './components/Counter'
import './App.css'

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: 1, value: 0 },
        { id: 2, value: 0 },
        { id: 3, value: 0 },
        { id: 4, value: 0 },
      ],
    }
  }

  onDecrement = e => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const data = state.data.map(item => {
        return { id: item.id, value: (item.value -= e) }
      })
      return {
        data,
      }
    })
  }

  onIncrement = e => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const data = state.data.map(item => {
        return { id: item.id, value: (item.value += e) }
      })
      return {
        data,
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state['data'].map(counter => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            value={counter.value}
            onIncrement={this.onIncrement}
            onDecrement={this.onDecrement}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Counter.js

```
export class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { value, onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props
    return (
      <div className="counter test">
        <b>{value}</b>
        <div className="counter-controls">
          <button
            className="button btn-danger btn-sm"
            onClick={() => onDecrement(1)}
          >
            -
          </button>
          <button
            className="button btn-success btn-sm"
            onClick={() => onIncrement(1)}
          >
            +
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Counter
```

Comment: You could pass the Id of the clicked element as well to the `onIncrement()` and then you'll find that specific object and set its value

Comment: Forgot to mention, that there can only be one parameter for the onIncrement() and it must define the amount I want to increase the counter by.

Comment: You could just add another prop, for `increment/decrement`, you could call it `step` and then use it in your `Counter` component

Comment: I can't, I wish it where that easy. It's a task I have to accomplish.

Comment: Are you incrementing and decrementing unique items in the `data` array cos i realized the increment applies the change to all items in the array, according to this component you've written

Answer (score 0):

I have added a new `prop` called `step` which can be changed to suit the billing. The `key` props is not advisable because it's only used for the React stuff and you're even using the id of the counter. Using a new prop would be advisable here.

i made some changes to your sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-shaw-fq6lc

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you can`t change Counter component. You can bind onIncrement and onDecrement in App.js, so props` callbacks semantic will not change for Counter.

```
onDecrement = (id, e) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const data = state.data.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return { id: item.id, value: (item.value -= e) };
        }
        return item;
      });
      return {
        data
      };
    });
  };

  onIncrement = (id, e) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const data = state.data.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return { id: item.id, value: (item.value += e) };
        }
        return item;
      });
      return {
        data
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state["data"].map(counter => (
          <Counter
            key={counter.id}
            value={counter.value}
            onIncrement={this.onIncrement.bind(this, counter.id)}
            onDecrement={this.onDecrement.bind(this, counter.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```